# DropDown selected value doesn't work with int type values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class in my asp.net project like this:

```
  public class CenterInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CenterName { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a dropdownlist ( contains `DataTextField="CenterName" DataValueField="ID"`) where has a list of CenterInfo as datasource,I tried to select an item in dropdownlist in code behind in this way:

```
CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue = Student.CenterID.ToString();
```

but it doesn't work, because dropdown values are in int type actually, and selected value is in string type. what can I do for that?

my aspx:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="CenterNameDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="requestdropdownlist" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CenterNameDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="CenterName" DataValueField="ID" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

and cs:

```
   CenterNameDropDownList.DataSource = Data.CenterDB.GetCenterByCityId(city.ID);
                CenterNameDropDownList.DataBind();
```

and related rendered html :

```
  <select name="ctl00$ContentsPlaceHolder$CenterNameDropDownList" id="ContentsPlaceHolder_CenterNameDropDownList" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled requestdropdownlist">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">سمنان : شهید عاملو</option>
    <option value="2">سمنان : شهید مطهری</option>
    <option value="3">سمنان : حکیم الهی</option>
    <option value="4">سمنان : شهید قندی</option>
    <option value="9">سمنان : جهادیه</option>
    <option value="47">سمنان : اعلاء</option>
    <option value="48">سمنان : اروانه</option>
    <option value="49">سمنان : بیابانک</option>
    <option value="50">سمنان : ایج</option>
    <option value="51">سمنان : خیرآباد</option>
    <option value="52">سمنان : لاسجرد</option>
    <option value="53">سمنان : پایگاه هوایی</option>
    <option value="54">سمنان : شهرک صنعتی سمنان</option>
    <option value="56">سمنان : آبخوری Wll</option>
    <option value="57">سمنان : اعلا Wll</option>
    <option value="58">سمنان : اسدآباد Wll</option>
    <option value="59">سمنان : دلازیان Wll</option>
    <option value="60">سمنان : دزهير Wll</option>
    <option value="61">سمنان : جام Wll</option>
    <option value="62">سمنان : خیرآباد Wll</option>
    <option value="63">سمنان : مومن آباد Wll</option>
    <option value="64">سمنان : افتر</option>
    <option value="65">سمنان : مومن اباد</option>
    <option value="175">سمنان : مهر 1 سمنان</option>
    <option value="177">سمنان : پشتیبانی سیستم جامع</option>
    <option value="182">سمنان : آزمایشی</option>
    <option value="191">سمنان : سمنان - مرکز مهر 2</option>

</select>
```

Comment: you could possibly set the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex instead

Comment: This has to work. Or what error you are getting? and check is any value is coming in Student.CenterID. let me know the issue

Comment: I tried DropDownList.Items.FindByValue but It didn't work too. when I bind my dropdown this get an error that says (For Example)  CenterDropDownList dosn't have an item with value "3" (because that item value is 3 not "3")

Comment: "but it doesn't work" does not provide enough info to help you. Your line of code should run after the DDL has been databound

Comment: I Explain that it get an error because my  dropdownlist doesn't have an item with "3" as value, because item's value is 3(int not string);

Comment: `.SelectedValue` is a string, therefore all values of all DropDown items are also strings (think about it, the rendered HTML results in `<option value="3">Text</option>` so the value is always a string, no matter what text it contains)

Comment: If the error is occuring, there is no `ListItem` entry in your list of `CentreCropownList.Items` collection with a `.Value` of `"3"`... make sure your dropdown is populated (either via the `.DataBind` or directly through `.Items.Add`) before you attempt to use `.SelectedValue`

Comment: @masoumehkarvar One thing here i would like to clarify, You are trying to get selected value? or setting default selected value of dropdown ?

Comment: @masoumehkarvar, If you check the items that are bound in the ddl, do you see a value that is 3 ??

Comment: @masoumehkavar See what happens if you override the ToString() of your CenterInfo class.  Just a guess, but see if it works.  From your ToString(), return CenterName.

Comment: @Suraj Singh : I want to get selected value

Comment: @masoumeh, sorry, you want to GET the selected value?? Everything has pointed to you SETTING the selected value, and everybody (with the obvious exception of Suraj) appears to have been under that impression. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @freefaller : sorry this was my mistake , I want to set selected value

Comment: @masoumehkarvar If you are assigning value to studentID than keep this on left side of the expression on right side will be the value you want to assign.

Comment: @Suraj Singh : sorry this was my mistake , I want to set selected value

Comment: @masoumehkarvar Again so does it solves your problem?

Comment: Sorry @masoume, but I give up - I've wasted far too much time because you're simply not being clear on what you require. Unless there is something really complex going on here, this is really, **really** simple coding. Good luck

Comment: @freefaller i had doubts about requirement from the start cause his code can easily set the default value but it didn't made any sense to set default value as per his code, but i was afraid to ask as it could attract negative votes if i say setting default selected value doesn't make sense, So you are not missing anything be sure about it.And really its a very simple coding thats why i didn't asked it first.Why so negative buddy ?

Comment: @freefaller : I dont Understand it yet. I have a page with  a list view of students, when user click on a row , he have to see second page that filled  with data about selected student. in second page I want to fill center dropdownlist with a list of Available centers (user can change it) and current student's center be selected on it. maybe this is simple but I dont get it yet.

Comment: @masoumehkarvar Simplest will be to pass `studentID` in querystring and using that id fetch Student details and fill all fields on Page_Load event , also populate dropdown for centres.

Comment: @Suraj Singh : I've done every thing you said and every thing work fine except center dropdownlist, as I have said I have an another DropDown in my page and it fill correct but not about center dropdown. but if I fill center dropdown by foreach statement and give id as int , it works.

Comment: any way I think I have to use foreach. Thanks for your time

Comment: @masoumehkarvar Do you need filtered options in center dropdown ? please post your code how are you populating your dropdown for centers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this what you need .

```
Student.CenterID = Convert.toInt32(CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop down list has t o bind like this way

```
CenterDropDownList.DataSource = centerInfoList;
CenterDropDownList.DataTextField = "CenterName";
CenterDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
CenterDropDownList.DataBind();
```

After this code only you can do

```
CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue = Student.CenterID.ToString();
```

Or

```
CenterDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(Student.CenterID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

And make sure the value of Student.CenterID should be there in the ID filed of CenterDropDownList

Try and let me know..

Comment: Try this.. ddlDistrict.Items.FindByValue("3").Selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

I replace this :

```
CenterNameDropDownList.DataSource = Data.CenterDB.GetCenterByCityId(city.ID);
```

with this:

```
 foreach (CenterInfo centerInfo in Data.CenterDB.GetCenterByCityId(city.ID))
                {
                    ListItem listitem = new ListItem();
                    listitem.Value = centerInfo.ID.ToString();
                    listitem.Text = centerInfo.CenterName;
                    CenterNameDropDownList.Items.Add(listitem);
                }
```

it work, but really there is no other way ?

Comment: Please confirm you definitely called `CenterNameDropDownList.DataBind()` **after** you set the `.DataSource`, `.DataTextField` and `.DataValueField`.  (And please note, if you replying directly to somebody in SO, who is not the original author, you must put their username starting with the @ sign for them to be notified)

Comment: Can you please provide how you are binding CenterNameDropDownList with entire code.Bcoz I think this is not the good way to bind a dropdownlist.

Comment: Not a problem - now, can you confirm what I've asked, and what Jidheesh is also asking. There is something not right in your code if you claim you're calling `.DataBind`, but without seeing the code, we can't really do anything to help

Comment: @Jidheesh Rajan : I use exactly your answer code. note that I have an another dropdown in same page that it works fine.but I don't no why this one doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is that centerInfoList not contain the item with ID=3. just for a test do this CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue="3"; will see it works

Comment: @masoumehkarvar, please do the following: comment out the `.SelectedIndex` line, then run your code. In your browser, copy and paste the **rendered HTML** from the `<select>` that you say doesn't have the "3" item in.  Please show us that rendered HTML

Comment: From the rendered HTML you've just provided, I can see absolutely no reason why `CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue = Student.CenterID.ToString()` would not work. That is assuming that `Student.CentreID` is an integer and set to the value `3`.

Comment: What is the type of the result returned by `GetCenterByCityId` ? If it is not IList/ICollection, try to convert it to List (`.ToList()`)

Answer (score 0):

*CenterDropDownList.SelectedValue = Student.CenterID.ToString();*

```
try
{
   CenterDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(Student.CenterID.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
finally
{

}
```